# How can I run electron application in background, like discord?

Tags: angular, electron

I am new in electron application development,looking for to run desktop application in background, and all APIs & process works in background, like discord.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't quit your app when your window close and add a system tray icon.
Everything in your main process will keep running in background.